# Where does req.param("insert_your_html_id_here") get its value from?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have these in my routing for POST.

```
console.log(req.param("ntg_div_workshop_slot_monday_edit_input_time_start_1"));
console.log(req.param("workshop_number_latitude_register"));
```

- The upper line returns undefined.
- The lower line returns a string as it is in the input field.

I here is my HTML codes for the respective lines of codes above.

```
<input
    class="
        form-control
        ntg-debug-dimension-height-px-45
    "
    id="ntg_div_workshop_slot_monday_edit_input_time_start_1"
    name="ntg_div_workshop_slot_monday_edit_input_time_start_1"
    placeholder="HHMM"
    type="number"
>
<input
    class="
        form-control
    "
    id="workshop_number_latitude_register"
    name="workshop_number_latitude_register"
    placeholder="Workshop Latitude."
    type="text"
>
```

Although not a direct child, both HTML codes are inside `<form></form>`.

I meant ideally both would return a value as it is in the input. But in this case of mine only `#workshop_number_latitude_register`returns value. What went wrong?

Comment: Note that [`req.param()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.param) is deprecated. You should reference [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) for POST submissions (along with using a body parser middleware to populate it) or [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) for GET.

Comment: Have you checked the request sent when submitting the form in your browser's dev tools, looking at the form data included? Does it list a value there for the 1st input?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MaJahSMc body also return `undefined`. How can you add data to be included from POST form submit button?

Comment: Okay I am stupid. It was a typo all along :(( sorry for taking your time. Anyway, how can I get `req.body."i_want_to_put_string_as_id_here"`?